# jQuery's .children() method returns 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my jQuery code, I want to be able to get the child element within a `<tr>` element. I have created a jQuery object and named the variable `$trElement`. However, for some reason calling `$trElement.children(".sequence-edit")` returns `undefined` so any further action done on that statement throws an error (since you are invoking a method on an undefined object). I have checked the HTML code of the parent element and it clearly contains a child element with the indicated class name. So why does it not work?

Here is the code I used to debug the issue.

```
console.log($trElement.html());
console.log($trElement.children(".sequence-edit"));
```

The first line `console.log($trElement.html());` logs:

```
<td class="sequence-number">#1</td>
<td class="sequence-data">
     <form action="editSequence.do" method="POST">
          <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="sequence" class="sequence-data-textarea"></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="index" value="0">
     </form>
</td>
<td class="button-first">

     <!-- Element targeting through ".sequence-class" -->
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info sequence-edit center-block display-true">EDIT</button>
     <button class="btn btn-info center-block edit-submit display-false" style="display: none;">SUBMIT</button>
</td>
<td class="button-second">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-modal-appearance center-block display-true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete-confirmation">DELETE</button>
     <button class="btn btn-warning center-block edit-cancel display-false" style="display: none;">CANCEL</button>
</td>
<td>
     <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-delete-selection center-block">
</td>
```

The second line `console.log($trElement.children(".sequence-edit"));` logs: `undefined`

Comment: use .find(...) i think

Comment: ^ I think it'd be $trElement.children().find(".sequence-edit")

Comment: that shouldn't be logging undefined, it should be an empty jQuery object.

Comment: The children of your TR element are the TD elements, and none of those has the class `sequence-edit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.children()` only travels one step into your selector's (`trElement`) DOM tree, (and those are your `<TD>`'s, not your `<button>`).

instead, use `.find(".sequence-edit")`

<del>https://api.jquery.com/children/</del>
**https://api.jquery.com/find/**

```js
var $trElement = $("tr");
console.log( $trElement.find(".sequence-edit").html() ); // "EDIT"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="sequence-number">#1</td>
    <td class="sequence-data">
      <form action="editSequence.do" method="POST">
        <textarea cols="50" rows="10" name="sequence" class="sequence-data-textarea"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="index" value="0">
      </form>
    </td>
    <td class="button-first">
      <!-- Element targeting through ".sequence-class" -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info sequence-edit center-block display-true">EDIT</button>
      <button class="btn btn-info center-block edit-submit display-false" style="display: none;">SUBMIT</button>
    </td>
    <td class="button-second">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete-modal-appearance center-block display-true" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-delete-confirmation">DELETE</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning center-block edit-cancel display-false" style="display: none;">CANCEL</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-delete-selection center-block">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works. For some reason I thought `child()` to `children()` was like `parent()` to `parents()`